# Do I need to update ExpressionEngine CMS Plugins or Modules?

Tags: content-management-system, updates, expressionengine

I have been working with Wordpress and Drupal for a while now, and something you have to do to maintain those CMSs is update themes, plugins, core, and modules.

My question is do you have to do that with the ExpressionEngine CMS? In the addons dropdown, there are modules, accessories, extentions, fieldtypes, and plugins. When I go to these, it doens't look like there is a way to update them. It shows what version there is, and I am able to delete them from there, but no updates anywhere in sight. Is it something I even need to do?

Thanks

Edit: I found the "update modules" button, but I still do not see anything like that for plugins, or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE doesn't make it quite as easy as it is in WordPress. You could check out the [Lamplighter](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lamplighter) extension to see what's still in need of an update then download from the respective source.

This is getting into opinion a bit but when I did a lot of EE dev, I usually stuck to the philosophy that if it worked, I used it and didn't worry about upgrading. Occasionally an extension/plugin would get a significant upgrade, a security patch, or have a feature implemented that I needed. That's That's when I'd go through the process of downloading and installing updates.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out Lamplighter. I am happy that at least on the modules, there is an update button.